# pass integer variable and string in os.system in python

Tags: python, os.system

I am getting **SyntaxError: invalid syntax** or **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s**) for +: 'int' and 'str'
. Here portnum is integer and the rest are string or

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
    import getpass
    import sys
    import MySQLdb
    import os    
    os.system('clear')   

    servname = raw_input("What's your server name? ")
    portnum = input("Your instance port number ? ")
    usrname = raw_input("What's your user name? ")
    print(  usrname + " is your username ?")
    passphrase = getpass.getpass("Enter password:")    

    cmdstr="/usr/local/bin/innotop -h " + servname + "-P ", portnum + "-u " +  usrname + "-p " + passphrase

    print(cmdstr)
    os.system("cmdstr")
```

Comment: You're omitting a bunch of `+` symbols when you assign `cmdstr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `+`, not a comma, between each element of a string concatenation, regardless of whether the elements are string literals or named variables. If you use a comma, you create a tuple. If you use nothing, you get a syntax error. Also, be sure to send the integer `portnum` to `str()`, so that it can be concatenated as a string.

```
cmdstr="/usr/local/bin/innotop -h " + servname + "-P " + str(portnum) + "-u " +  usrname + "-p " + passphrase
```

Also, don't send the literal string `'cmdstr'` to `os.system()`; that's not what you would enter into a command line. You want to send the value that that variable points to, just like you did when you printed it:

```
os.system(cmdstr)
```